# pass var to routes - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem passing an object through a route, this is my server.js

```
var jwt         = require('jsonwebtoken');
var socketioJwt = require('socketio-jwt');
var app         = require('koa')();
var server      = require('http').createServer(app.callback());
var io          = require('socket.io')(server);
var socket      = require('./api/lib/socket.js')(app,io,socketioJwt);
var router  = require('./api/router');
app.use(views('views', {map:{html:'swig'}}));
router(app,jwt);
```

this is my routes.js

```
var route = require('koa-route');
module.exports = function router(app,jwt)
{   
    app.use(route.post('/login/auth', require('./routes/auth')(jwt));

};
```

and this is my auth:

```
module.exports = function *(jwt) {

  var profile = {
    first_name: 'a',
    last_name: 'b',
    email: 'a@gb.com',
    id: 0
  };

  var input = this.request.body;
  var token = jwt.sign(profile, input.password, { expiresIn: 60*5 });

  this.cookies.set('access_token', token, { signed: false });
  this.body = token;
};
```

the problem is that passing jet I get: `status code must be a number` where is the error?

Comment: Why export the generator function in `auth`? replace it with normal function to export?

Comment: Either your code, or some middleware, is calling `response.status()` with a non-numerical value.